# Ignore Inf value and run a lm Regression

Tags: r

these are my variables:

```
> dput(y)
c(-22.0713165394207, 14.0880914427811, 10.9650636244176, -1.96648890706268, 
-5.30593850426708, -7.54651916037787, 3.84914747321197, 4.4986386904214, 
1.73067625014435, 2.5585960595839, -2.72766183793304, -3.10167452216202, 
2.68853838208521, 1.12662203717498, 1.24951279248057, 3.70075666289518, 
-6.11243972144607, -6.91019769671849, 6.46767794752582, 8.84874735514293, 
2.95606352319898, 3.23883851668917, -2.61692776879569)
> dput(x)
c(`1` = 0.0520523266234464, `2` = Inf, `3` = 0.0520523266234462, 
`4` = 0.0520523266234463, `5` = 0.0520523266234463, `6` = 0.0520523266234461, 
`7` = 0.0520523266234463, `8` = 0.0520523266234466, `9` = 0.0520523266234465, 
`10` = 0.0520523266234465, `11` = 0.0520523266234465, `12` = 0.0520523266234466, 
`13` = 0.0520523266234468, `14` = 0.0520523266234466, `15` = 0.0520523266234467, 
`16` = 0.0520523266234464, `17` = 0.0520523266234463, `18` = 0.0520523266234465, 
`19` = 0.0520523266234466, `20` = 0.0520523266234463, `21` = 0.0520523266234464, 
`22` = 0.0520523266234465, `23` = 0.0520523266234464)
```

When I run my regression: `summary(lm(ex.return ~ ex.return.skew))`

I have this error message:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
```

I tried to delete the positon 2 and then run my regression but I can not do this because data is much bigger. So I am looking for a way to ignore the Inf/Na values and run my regression.

How can I do this?

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean that you cannot delete that observation?

Comment: Because, in this specific case It would easy to delete the second position and run the regression. But my data is much bigger than this. It wouldnt be functional to do this.

Answer (score 1):

We can convert the infinite values to `NA` and it should work

```
x[is.infinite(x)] <- NA
summary(lm(y ~ x))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun but I have NA value for the angular  coefficient of my regression. I though it would work, but it didnt. I tried `na.action=na.omit´ but didnt work.

Comment: @Laura  Would it make sense to create a logical index and then ignore those values. i.e. `i1 <- is.infinite(x); i2 <- is.infinite(y); i3 <- i1|i2; x1 <- x[!i3]; y1 <- y[!i3]; summary(lm(y1 ~ x1))`

Comment: @akrun this answer doesn’t work because you can’t have NA values in a regression as you get NA coefficients as mentioned. See my solution for the correct answer. The lm function always works best with data.frames rather than separate vectors - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the infinite items in both x and y as follows:

```
summary(lm(ex.return[is.finite(df$ex.return)] ~ ex.return.skew[is.finite(df$ex.return)]))
```

However, what is better is to put them into a data.frame and add that data.frame in the data argument of lm which filters out the rows of the data.frame.

```
df <- data.frame(ex.return, ex.return.skew)
summary(lm(ex.return ~ ex.return.skew, df[is.finite(df$ex.return),]))
```

Note that is.finite() works for NA values as well as -Inf/Inf

```
is.finite(c(NA, Inf, 10))
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

If there is the possibility of Inf/-Inf and NA in any row of any column in your data.frame (i.e. not just in ex.return) then you might need to do something like:

```
summary(lm(ex.return ~ ex.return.skew, df[is.finite(rowSums(df)),]))
```